# PythonOperator in Airflow 2.3.1 using partial() and expand()

Tags: python, dynamic, parallel-processing, airflow

I'm interested in creating dynamic processes, so I saw the `partial()` and `expand()` methods in the 2.3 version of `airflow`.

I have implemented the following code:

```py
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pendulum

local_tz = pendulum.timezone("America/Mexico_City")

@task
def add_one(x):
    print(x)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Me',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': dt(2020, 7, 17, tzinfo = local_tz),
}

with DAG('dag_test_j',
         default_args = default_args,
         schedule_interval = '0 07 10,25 * *',
         catchup = False,
         concurrency = 4,  
         max_active_runs = 1
         ) as dag:

    python_test = PythonOperator.partial(
        task_id="python_test_task",
        python_callable=add_one,
    ).expand(op_kwargs={'x':[1,2,3]})

python_test
```

The problem are the args. I'm getting the following error:

```
[2022-05-27, 14:08:37 CDT] {taskinstance.py:1570} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=Me
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=dag_test_j
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=python_test_task
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-05-28T00:08:36.518574+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2022-05-28T00:08:36.518574+00:00
[2022-05-27, 14:08:37 CDT] {taskinstance.py:1890} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 168, in execute
    context_merge(context, self.op_kwargs, templates_dict=self.templates_dict)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/context.py", line 256, in context_merge
    context.update(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/_collections_abc.py", line 946, in update
    for key, value in other:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Just one instance ran and i already tried putting another values in the .expand(op_kwargs={'x':[1,2,3]}) method, like:

```
expand(op_kwargs={'x':[1,2,3],'y':[1,2]})
```

This ran 2 instances instead of 1.
Also tried:

```
.expand(1,op_kwargs={'x':[1,2,3]})
```

This gives me an error in the main screen:

```
Broken DAG: [/root/airflow/dags/dag_test_i copy.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/root/airflow/dags/dag_test_i copy.py", line 28, in <module>
    python_test = PythonOperator.partial(
TypeError: expand() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/ and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. We are not interested in your personal background as a programmer; we *are* interested in a *clear, specific question* - ideally, one asked explicitly, starting with a question word like "why" or "how" and ending with a question mark (`?`). It would especially help to explain *what the code is intended to do*, and to clarify "The problem are the args" (arguments *of/for what*?).

Comment: there is open issue about it : https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/23833

Comment: I will follow the issue.
Thank u so much! @ozs

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax is list of `op_kwargs` for each mapped task: `expand(op_kwargs=[{'x':1}, {'x':2}, {'x':3}])` or `expand_kwargs([{'x':1}, {'x':2}, {'x':3}])` instead of `expand(op_kwargs={'x':[1,2,3]})`, and you can provide different `op_kwargs` for each task, ex: `expand_kwargs([{'x':1, 'y': 1}, {'x':2}, {'x':3, 'z': 3}])`

And remove the decorator `task` before `add_one` where you run it in a PythonOperator

```py
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pendulum

local_tz = pendulum.timezone("America/Mexico_City")

def add_one(x):
    print(x)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Me',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': dt(2020, 7, 17, tzinfo = local_tz),
}

with DAG('dag_test_j',
         default_args = default_args,
         schedule_interval = '0 07 10,25 * *',
         catchup = False,
         concurrency = 4,  
         max_active_runs = 1
         ) as dag:

    python_test = PythonOperator.partial(
        task_id="python_test_task",
        python_callable=add_one,
    ).expand_kwargs([{'x':1}, {'x':2}, {'x':3}])

python_test
```